# Connecting to my Spectrum Wi-Fi on Ubuntu not working

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I was able to install Linux alongside my Windows OS (dual boot) but now I'm having trouble connecting wirelessly to my Spectrum router and modem. I called technical support at Spectrum but they weren't able to help me. I also get an error message when I try to find my network that says: "No Wi-fi adapter found: Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged in and turned on". I used the terminal to type in some commands to search for hidden networks but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Thanks, waltinator. I think I need to find out if I can download a network adapter driver my HP Pavilion laptop from https://www.kernel.org/ I don't have a flash drive at the moment so will have to wait until tomorrow to buy one.

Comment: A German software engineer told me that the list of drivers on that website won't help me. I am looking into his suggestions instead.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem that I had issues with my Homemade Raspberry Pi Weather Station, I was using Linux-python-SSH to send data files from my Raspberry Pi Weather Station to my Raspberry Pi-Zero Weather Station Monitor display. After I changed to Spectrum I found I could not communicate using SSH to the Pi-Zero Display. After searching the internet I found an article saying that Linux doesn't work well on a Spectrum wifi router. Talked to a Spectrum Tech and he admitted that Linux does not work as well with a Spectrum router( also I can save $5 a month on not renting the Spectum router). I found a wifi router on line, TP-Link Archer A7, installed it. This solved my problem.
Sorry for your problem, I was surprised that there was NOT more info on this issue on the internet. The change in router worked GREAT for me.
Good Luck,
Rog

Comment: From what I can see "Spectrum Wifi" is an ISP charging for Wifi as a seperate service. They seems to supply a number of routers, including common household brands such as Netgear, TPLink, Sagecom and Technicolor.  Not everyone can afford to go buy a new modem.  If you wish to share your own experience, please add a comment not an answer.  Thank you.